# Django Render HTML to PDF

Tags: html, django, django-templates

I'm trying to render an html file to pdf however while the pdf functionality is working fine the rendering is working properly, no css. Also it renders the whole page, how can i render specific sections of the html page. I'm using xhtml2pdf.

views.py file

```
from io import BytesIO
from django.http import HttpResponse
from django.template.loader import get_template
from django.views import View
from xhtml2pdf import pisa

def render_to_pdf(template_src, context_dict={}):
    template = get_template(template_src)
    html  = template.render(context_dict)
    result = BytesIO()
    pdf = pisa.pisaDocument(BytesIO(html.encode("utf-8")), result)
    if not pdf.err:
        return HttpResponse(result.getvalue(), content_type='application/pdf')
    return None

data = {
    "company": "Name",
    }


#Opens up page as PDF
class ViewPDF(View):
    def get(self, request, *args, **kwargs):

        pdf = render_to_pdf('listings/listing.html', data)
        return HttpResponse(pdf, content_type='application/pdf')
```

**urls.py file**

```
path('pdf_view/', views.ViewPDF.as_view(), name="pdf_view"),
```

**html file**

```
<section class="p0">
        <div class="container">
            <div class="row listing_single_row">
                <div class="col-sm-6 col-lg-7 col-xl-8">
                    <div class="single_property_title">
                        <a href="{{ listing.photo_1.url }}" class="upload_btn popup-img"><span class="flaticon-photo-camera"></span> View Photos</a>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="col-sm-6 col-lg-5 col-xl-4">
                    <div class="single_property_social_share">
                        <div class="spss style2 mt10 text-right tal-400">
                            <ul class="mb0">
                                <li class="list-inline-item"><a href="#"><span class="flaticon-transfer-1"></span></a></li>
                                <li class="list-inline-item"><a href="#"><span class="flaticon-heart"></span></a></li>
                                <li class="list-inline-item"><a href="#"><span class="flaticon-share"></span></a></li>
                                <li class="list-inline-item"><a href="{% url 'pdf_view' %}"><span class="flaticon-printer"></span></a></li>
                            </ul>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </section>
```

Thank you!

Comment: I think you need to include bootstrap css/js in the html file because it's an independent template which has no relations with any other template in templates directory

Answer (score 0):

Ans 1.) If you want to style your html than directly use style property in tag. If you make class and use template inheritance than it is not going to work as it is independent html. Use style directly in html.
Ans 2.) if you want specific section of html in pdf than write content which you need in html or use style = “display: none ;” on section which you dont want in pdf.

Answer (score 0):

I am also facing same issue and hadn't find any reasonable solution of why **div** is not supported in **html to pdf in django** . It means that I am not viewing the same **div** as in html. I want to align the different **div in horizontal and in inline-block** but it is not working in my case.
Your opinion is helpful to me

Comment: I would suggest you to post this answer as new question and refer to this question as an answered question, so that people will notice it.